# Modifying "this" variables

Tags: javascript

I was playing around with modifying Array Prototype, but I'm stumped at this part. Would be great if you could help me.

Alright, suppose I want to add a function "Parent" to Array.prototype

```
Array.prototype.Parent = function() { 
    console.log(this);
}
```

Next, I want to add a Child function to the Parent function. I would do it like this:

```
Array.prototype.Parent.Child = function() { 
    console.log(this);
}
```

Now, I want both this in Parent and Child to refer to the array itself. So:

```
[1,2,3].Parent(); // Would output [1,2,3];
[1,2,3].Parent.Child(); // Want it to print [1,2,3];
```

Basically, I want this variable in child to refer to the array instead of the Parent Function. Any insight?

Comment: It's not possible.

Comment: `var x = [1,2,3]; x.Parent.Child.bind(x)();`

Comment: Can you just pass the array as a parameter to the function?

Comment: @Dai, but I don't know what x is in the first place to do something like that.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice - No parameter can be passed, unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `Parent` a getter that returns a unique function for each array, providing context:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'parent', {
    configurable: true,
    get: function () {
        var that = this;

        function parent() {
            console.log(that);
        }

        parent.child = function () {
            console.log(that);
        };

        return parent;
    },
});
```

Comment: Then the Parent would be an object/class and can't be used as a function =/

Comment: @Noobit: Ah, sorry, it can still be a function; you just have to attach the `Child` property manually (`var f = function () { /* parent things */ }; f.Child = function () { /* child things */ };`) or use an ES6 class extending `Function`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is how the `this` variable is identified if you have a series of object lookups then a function call. Like this.

```
foo.bar.baz.qux();
```

The qux method has a this value equal to `foo.bar.baz`.
So in essence functions in javascript have a hidden argument `this` that is the object they are called on.

There is no way to modify this behavior in javascript.

Comment: The `this` value can be changed using `bind`.

Comment: @Dai What would they bind it to? Binding it to `Array.prototype` wouldn't produce the `[1,2,3]` output.

Answer (score 0):

You can reassign `this` using `Function.bind`.

```
var myArray = [1,2,3];

myArray.Parent.Child.bind( myArray )();
```

In my example, `myArray.Parent.Child` is the `Function` you defined in your example - then we use `bind` to create a copy of the function with `this` set to `myArray`, then we use the `()` operator to invoke it.

This can be reduced to a single line with a self-executing lambda (ES6):

```
( x => x.Parent.Child.bind( x )() )( myArray );
```

...which is equivalent to this in ES5:

```
( function( x ){ return x.Parent.Child.bind( x )() } )( myArray );
```

Comment: This is a lot of manual work, and I have to know the array initially. The idea of adding to prototype is to propagate to all newly created array, which has a structure I wouldn't have any idea about in the first place.